# How to access the mysql_fetch_array function output outside of the while loop...?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to access the $Frined_Id outside the while loop. But it is only returning the last accessed element. Is there any method so that i can store the value of Friend Id inside the array and then can use them in program whenever i want.

```
$query="SELECT * FROM `user_friend` WHERE `User_Id`='$id'";
if($query_run=mysql_query($query))
    {
    $mysql_num_rows=mysql_num_rows($query_run);
    $i=$mysql_num_rows;
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query_run))
        {
            $Friend_Id=$row['Friend_Id'];
            $Name=$row['Friend_Name'];
            $Name_array=array("$Name");
            echo "<a href=\"view_profile.php?id=$Friend_Id\"/>".$Name."</a>".'<br>';

        }
        echo $Friend_Id;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it only shows the last one is because it gets changed each time in the loop and the last thing it was set to is what it is. A fix for being able to access all of them is make $Friend_Id an array as such:

```
$Friend_Id[] = $row['Friend_Id'];
```

Then after your loop, you can access them by index

```
// Show the first one
echo("Friend ID is " . $Friend_Id[0]);

// Show the third one
echo("Friend ID is " . $Friend_Id[2]);
```

You can make it even more useful by making an associative array containing the name and id like:

```
$friend[] = Array($Name => $Friend_Id);
```

Just a few ideas...

Answer (score 0):

If you're only getting one result (if the ID is unique), don't use a loop at all.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM 'user_friend' WHERE 'User_Id'= $id LIMIT 1";
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query_run);
...
echo $row['Friend_Id'];
```

Then you don't have to worry about if the value is only available inside the loop.